# Dynkin systems question

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{G}\subset\mathcal{P}(X)$ (the power set of $X$), $\delta(\mathcal{G})$ is the Dynkin system generated by $\mathcal{G}$.

Assume $\mathcal{G}$ is stable under finite intersections and define $D_G$ as 
$$D_G:=\{Q\subset X: Q \cap G \in \delta(\mathcal{G})\}$$

There's a statement in my textbook (the proof is left for the reader) that goes as follows: 
$$\mathcal{G}\subset D_G, \forall G\in \mathcal{G}$$

I think that I understand the idea, but I haven't been able to formalise it.

I would appreciate any hint, thanks in advance!

EDIT: Is it enough to say that:

If $\mathcal{G}\subset D_G$ this implies (by definition) that $\mathcal{G}\cap G=G \in \delta({\mathcal{G}})$ (which is true since $G\in \mathcal{G}\subset \delta(\mathcal{G})$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that for an arbitrary $G,G' \in \mathcal{G}$ we have $G' \in D_G$:

$G' \subseteq X$ and since $\mathcal{G}$ is stable under finite intersection, we have $G \cap G' \in \mathcal{G} \subseteq \delta(\mathcal{G})$ i.e. $G' \in D_G$.